# What part of speech is "no" - negative pronoun, adverb or something else?

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, negation, parts-of-speech

Is **"no"** - a negative pronoun, adverb or something else?

> 1. There was **no** reply.
> 2. The song was **no** strain on her voice.

What do you think about this?

> **Negative sentences** with introductory "there" are formed in the usual way for the verbs which are their predicates, that is, by means of
>   appropriate auxiliaries for all the verbs but to be. In the latter
>   case two negative constructions are possible:
>
> a) either with the **negative pronoun no**, as in:
>
> There was no sign of him in the hall.
>
> There is no knowing when he will
>   come...(http://doclecture.net/1-7538.html)

Comment: In this context it's a *quantifier*, like *one*, *two*, *some*, *many*. A quantifier  is a sort of *determiner*, which is the class to which articles (*a, the*) also belong.

Comment: Sorry,but that's probably a highly academic view on problem. I  have never heard of "quantifier" and in my school we don't single out "determiners"

Comment: If your teachers are resolutely traditionalist and turn their backs on  everything that's happened in English grammar for the last eighty years, you may preserve them from shock by calling it an *adjective*. But note that it unlike an adjective it can take the same syntactic role as an article.and unlike an adjective it does not  inflect -- there's no *noer, noest*.

Comment: If you don't single out "determiners", then you aren't learning a useful version of English grammar.

Comment: @StoneyB,  snailboat - nice job of undermining a student's confidence in the education being received.

Comment: First of all "no" in the above use is an adjective describing quantity such as all, every, each, many etc. It can't be a pronoun as it is coupled with a noun.

Comment: @ASTPace That's probably a good thing. There's too little critical evaluation of grammar among the general public.

Comment: Is no an adverb?
as I am very confused with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a pronoun because it doesn't take the place of a noun - not by itself anyway.  *No one*/*nobody*/*nothing*/*nowhere* would be some of the "pronoun forms" of *no*.

*No* generally modifies a noun so that makes it technically an adjective.  When modifying a verb or adjective *not* is used.

*No* is also a typically a [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) - which can be considered a special type of adjective - because it can occupy the "spot" where an article or word like *this*/*that*/*these*/*those* would go.

Comment: Then please,tell me in what case "no" is a negative pronoun?

Comment: It's never a pronoun.

Comment: But I gave you a theoretical material that says the opposite:Negative sentences with introductory "there" are formed **a) either with the negative pronoun no, as in:** There was **no** sign of him in the hall.....

Comment: Your theoretical material is wrong or copied incorrectly.  Well - I have heard words like *his*, *her* said to be *possessive* pronouns, but *no* doesn't have an antecedent like a pronoun does, so I again FWIW your theoretical material is using the wrong terminology IMHO.

Comment: And a property of any pronoun is that you can replace it with an actual noun.  You can't do that with e.g. "no sign" - the noun is already there.

Comment: What syntactic role does this "no" perform?

Comment: @Daisy: In the case of "There was no sign of him in the hall", *no* is a determiner.